# AJAX receives multiple results from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I hope someone can help get it sorted, AJAX receives only one result to display on select dropdown. It looks like this Model1Model2Model3Model4. I wanted to look like this

Model1

Model2

Model3

Model4

where would look like this on jquery script:

```
$('#input_11_183').append('Model1');

$('#input_11_183').append('Model2');

$('#input_11_183').append('Model3');

$('#input_11_183').append('Model4');
```

and all these data will be added to a select dropdown field

Here are my php codes:

```
<?php
function list_of_brandcars() {
    $model_option = $_POST['pass_data'];  

    $carposts = array(             
        'post_type' => 'list_of_cars',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',              
        's'     => $model_option
        );                  

    $att = new WP_Query($carposts);
    $count=0;
    if($att->have_posts()){
    
        while($att->have_posts()) : $att->the_post();                                
                while(have_rows('mods')) : the_row();                                                             
                    echo get_sub_field('model');                   
                endwhile;                  
        endwhile;

    }
    die(); 
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_list_of_brandcars', 'list_of_brandcars');
add_action('wp_ajax_list_of_brandcars', 'list_of_brandcars');
?>
```

and here is my jQuery script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) { 
    
    $('#input_11_11').change(function(){
        var from_brand = $(this).val();
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,   
            data: {     
                action: 'list_of_brandcars',                        
                pass_data: from_brand
            },
            success: function(data) {           
                $('#input_11_183').empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {             
                    $('#input_11_183').append('<option value="' + data + '">' + data + '</option>');
                }
            }
        });
        die();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: try these dataType: "json",  contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8" after url and Json.parse(data); in success

Comment: @SyedMuhammadShakaybAthar nice idea to set `dataType: "json"`, but if the server isn't outputting JSON to begin with (which it isn't) then all this will do is cause a JS error when it finds it can't parse the data. And setting `contentType` is just wrong for this, because that's about what AJAX is _sending_, not _receiving_. You can read about it in the JQuery $.ajax documentation if you're unclear.

Comment: Do you really have a Javascript function called `die();`? What does it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're outputting raw strings, which just gets concatatenated together and becomes a single line of text in the response. You need to output some structured data in JSON format. To achieve that, first make an array, and then add each piece of text to the array.

Here's an example. I've added comments everywhere I've added or changed something in the code:

PHP

```
$att = new WP_Query($carposts);
$count=0;
$response = array(); //make empty array

if($att->have_posts()){
    while($att->have_posts()) : $att->the_post();                                
            while(have_rows('mods')) : the_row();                                                             
                $response[] = get_sub_field('model'); //add to the array
            endwhile;                  
    endwhile;
}

echo json_encode($response); //encode the array as JSON and output it
die();
```

JavaScript:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        dataType: "json", //tell jQuery to expect JSON in the response, and automatically parse it
        data: {     
            action: 'list_of_brandcars',                        
            pass_data: from_brand
        },
        success: function(data) {           
            $('#input_11_183').empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {             
                $('#input_11_183').append('<option value="' + data[i] + '">' + data[i] + '</option>'); //access the correct element of (what is now) an array of strings.
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you, this works.. Thank you so much brother

Comment: No problem. If the answer has helped you, please remember to mark it as "accepted" (you can click on the tick mark next to the question so it turns green). Thanks :-)

Comment: thank you. I also just knew this thing.